# Unable to connect to cloud JIRA

Tags: python, python-requests, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm trying to connect to cloud JIRA with basic authentication REST API using python language. If I'm passing the username and password directly to JIRA method like this: `jira = JIRA(base_url, basic_auth=('user@domain.com','password'))` then the connection is getting established. However, if I'm reading username and password from a file and assigning them to variables and passing those variables in JIRA method like this:

```
user:login_detail[0]
password:login_detail[1]
jira = JIRA(base_url, basic_auth=(user,password))
```

then it gives the following error:

> WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET
>   https://.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3]
>   in 14.218200198444048s. Err: 401

I googled the above error and found some articles around this. I had tried the solutions. however, they didn't work. Does anybody have an idea, what should be the problem? Is there any other method to establish a connection to JIRA? Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I was reading the file with '`login_detail = f.readline()`' method which are adding an extra character(next line) in the list 'login_detail'. Hence, I changed the read method with '`login_detail = f.read().splitlines()`' which exclude the '\n' character from the string.